# Setting the script tag to access the new angular router

Tags: angular-new-router

I am starting to play with the new angular router.  I did an npm install as was noted https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-new-router.   However, I am having difficulty setting up the script tag.

I am playing around with a tutorial to work with the router and the author sets up his router as so...

```
<script src="lib/router.es5.js">
```

However I am unable to access the script.  I looked through the files on the node module.

I can find the **router.es5.js**  file in the **docs folder**  that runs inside the  **dist folder.**

However I am unable to get that running. I have tried changing my folder name to be a better match.  However, I am still not correctly accessing the file.

Additionally, I tried to go through the entire file directory with no success.

```
<script src="/angular-new-router/dist/docs/router.es5.js"></script>
```

I know this tutorial was from last April, so I am wondering if something has changed or if there is another way to make an install or how others are setting up their path?

***** update ***** i am following the link https://github.com/angular/router/pull/252/files.

I copied the script tag that the author is using on this

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-new-router/dist/router.es5.js"></script>
```

This makes sense as the file is going through the node modules folder. I will change this to the answer unless someone knows a better/more correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [discussion I had with Brandon Roberts](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3774) (towards the bottom), who seems to be in the know.

I've been using the [router code referenced in his Github repo](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angularjs-component-router/blob/master/lib/angular_1_router.js).

NOTE: This answer will no doubt be out of date very soon!

Comment: Awesome share.  I really appreciate it.  We are going to start playing with this at work.  I did the install on his repo.  Came across a couple of errors in my console, but the code is a great place to start.